# Pagination: redirect to same URL but replacing single parameter

Tags: java, playframework

I have an scala.html component which generates a number of pagination buttons like:

[image]

The question is how can I set `href` for those buttons to make them lead to same URL but replacing only `page` url-param?

I have several controllers and they get several optional URL parameters including page number.

```
controllers.ItemController.list(
    type: Integer ?= null,
    group: Integer ?= null,
    page: Integer ?= 1
)

controllers.GroupController.list(
    type: Integer ?= null,
    category: Integer ?= null,
    page: Integer ?= 1
)
```

The problem is that I have to hard-code custom paginator for each controller.

Comment: What's wrong with passing the page in? Setting the href to something like `href="@routes.Application.index(page = pageNumber)"` (where pageNumber is the current page) works fine.

Comment: Value of `href` depends on current view. In some places I need
`@routes.ItemController.list(page = p)` in others I need `@routes.GroupController.list(page = p)` or `CategoryController` etc.

Also if current view was requested with some URL parameters, I want them to remain on other pages.

So if user filtered items by type requesting `@routes.ItemController.list(type = t)` then `href` must refer to `@routes.ItemController.list(type = t, page = p)` and keep every other possible URL parameter.

Comment: The only solution for now is to parse requested URL, insert or replace page parameter and then use resulted value for `href`.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way except to handle it in front end side. That's what I did in my web app.